# Garageband does not detect my Audio Unit v3

Tags: macos, core-audio, audiounit, xcode7.3

I've been coding this AUv3 effect which runs fine when loaded into a previously compiled Apple's AUv3Host app. Then I've tried to load it into Garageband 10.2.0 (latest) and did not appear in plugins list. I also tried AULab not appearing in plugins list either, but this time Xcode returned this error: "**Error opening component myAUv3 : -10863**"

I ran **auval -v** returning "AU VALIDATION SUCCEEDED."

Any ideas to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: I guess that the reason why AULab returns the error described above is as mentioned by Apple's staff: "(...) the current version of AU Lab is not instantiating v3 Audio Units asynchronously (which is why they fail to load). "

Comment: Did you solve this? There are other ways to test besides AULab and GarageBand, but I wanted to know if you have any more information or if you're even interested in this anymore.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka, I'm not up-to-date with Apple's audio dev newsletter at the moment. I didn't solve this. Apologies for answering back to you only now.

Comment: I was going to suggest AudioKit's Audio Unit Manager as another app that you could test your v3 in.  It's an example inside AudioKit, which is free and open source so you can probably get it to give you a lot better debug information than AULab or Garageband.